# How to prioritize a file import over another file

Tags: php, function, joomla

Hi I am looking for a solution to give priority to File-B over File-A. Let me explain.

I am running Joomla and My template is in Blocks which are all imported and joined in the main `index.php` file.

Lets us say I have 2 folders **FOLDER-A** and **FOLDER-B**

**FOLDER-A** CONTENTS:

```
head.php
header.php
mainbody.php
footer.php
```

I am using the following function to get them to my `index.php` file:

```
function getBlock($filename){
require_once(YOURBASEPATH.DS.'FOLDER-A'.DS.$filename.'.php');
}
```

and I call them as:

```
<?php className::getBlock('head') ?>

<?php className::getBlock('header') ?>

<?php className::getBlock('mainbody') ?>

<?php className::getBlock('footer') ?>
```

Now I want to create an option of altering these core files without disturbing the original.

So if one wants to make changes to the Main Body then he copies the file `mainbody.php` to a filder called **FOLDER-B** and incorporates the changes there.

So what I am looking for is a function which checks FOLDER-B first and if a file with the same name of it's counterpart as in **FOLDER-A** exists, then it must load that otherwise it should load the **regular file from FOLDER-A**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like:

```
function getBlock($filename){
  $fileB = YOURBASEPATH.DS.'FOLDER-B'.DS.$filename.'.php';
  if (file_exists($fileB)) {
    require_once($fileB); 
  } else {
    require_once(YOURBASEPATH.DS.'FOLDER-A'.DS.$filename.'.php'); 
  }
}
```

?

Answer (score 1):

```
function getBlock($filename){

    $folders = array(
        YOURBASEPATH.DS.'FOLDER-B',
        YOURBASEPATH.DS.'FOLDER-A',
    );

    foreach ($folders as $folder) {
        $file = $folder.DS.$filename.'.php';
        if ( file_exists($file) ) {
            require_once ($file);
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You're including both of them, need a break;

Comment: Hey @Anatoly thanks for responding. Yep your code works and even the code from @Madas works fine. I am voting for your question but also accepting @Madas's Answer because I'll be using that finally because basically it is a little more compact than yours and I can only accept any one answer.

Comment: Both codes works fine. But this code is more universal, you can add to array one more folder and this code will work with three folders, priority by array index